# how to specifiy colour theme in VBA

Tags: excel, charts, pie-chart, vba

I would like to manually specify the colours in a colour theme which I use in VBA.

My function looks like this

```
    Function GetColorScheme(i As Long) As String
Const thmColor1 As String = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Document Themes 14\Theme Colors\Blue Green.xml"
Const thmColor2 As String = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Document Themes 14\Theme Colors\Orange Red.xml"
    Select Case i Mod 2
        Case 0
            GetColorScheme = thmColor1
        Case 1
            GetColorScheme = thmColor2
    End Select
End Function
```

in the moment I use the path to the colour schemes to define the themes. However as soon as the path woudl change the macro stops working. Is there any way to define the colour theme to use IN VBA? For Example

```
Const thmColor1 As String = RGB.....
```

I woudl appreciate any comments

Answer (score 0):

Your function could be improved in this way:

```
Function GetColorSchemeRGB(i As Long) As Long

    Select Case i Mod 2
        Case 0
            'for red
            GetColorSchemeRGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Case 1
            'for green
            GetColorSchemeRGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    End Select
End Function
```

You can't assign your Const in this way:

```
Const thmColor1 As Long = RGB(255, 255, 255)
```

as it's required to assign value to Const. Alternatively you could make check in immediate to find which long represent which RGB value like this:

```
'for white
Debug.Pring RGB(255,255,255)
16777215  '<<result
```

and than you will define your Const in this way:

```
'for white
Const thmColor1 As Long = 16777215
```

which could be add to your function in the way you want it.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I shoudl have mentioned that the elements I am colouring this way are pie charts, which means I would have to be able to specify 2 different colours for each CASE (because there are two different section (slices ) in each pie- coudl you maybe incorporate this point in the answer that woudl be really helpful

Comment: is there no way ti implement more tahn a single colour into the case construct?

Comment: @TimonHeinomann, you could add as many `Case section` as you need to your (proposed) function.